# select a subset of a sting identifiing the digits and certain letter in any combination and in any order

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, t-sql

Hope you can help me.

I am trying to split a column list of strings into information that i can use.
In this string usually there is a name and a booking reference.
The booking reference is a set of numbers(digits) they appear in any part of the string.
eg below 
Also sometimes it has a KX infront of the digits as they are KX books, but not always.
If i could create a new temp table splitting the data i could use it to match another table to verify payment.

so this is the dummy column that i am working with:

```
Narrative
simon says KX1234
Tracy Jones kx 2456
KX3887Candy min
Shelly 9876
3424Tom
kx5436michaelstone
4353 Diana 
kx Anglia
9387
kx 2423
kx4645 
James tin
receipted twice 
12322452 AG
```

sometimes there are linked kx references in the narrative eg 8765jones8767 
sometimes there are no numbers in the select list i create just a name.. i'll have to work out how to link them some how else.

So i am interested in the digits and esp if there is a Kx linked to it.
if i can create a table with just the kx next to a column with the digits and another column with say their name

Comment: This looks like a bit of a mess.  Have you tried anything yourself?  You should be able to use a mixture of CHARINDEX and SUBSTRING to parse these things apart, but it doesn't look to follow anything standard.

Answer (score 0):

```
Declare @YourTable table (Narrative varchar(50))
Insert Into @YourTable values
('simon says KX1234'),
('Tracy Jones kx 2456'),
('KX3887Candy min'),
('Shelly 9876'),
('3424Tom'),
('kx5436michaelstone'),
('4353 Diana'), 
('kx Anglia'),
('9387'),
('kx 2423'),
('kx4645'), 
('James tin'),
('receipted twice '),
('12322452 AG')


Select A.*
      ,Has_KX = Sign(CharIndex('KX',Narrative))
      ,Digits = B.Value
 From  @YourTable A
 Cross Apply (
              Select Value=(Select ''+RetVal 
               From (Select RetSeq=N
                           ,RetVal=Substring(A.Narrative,N,1) 
                     From  (Select Top 10000 N=Row_Number() over(order by number) From master..spt_values ) N
                     Where Substring(A.Narrative,N,1) like '[0-9]'
                    ) C For XML Path (''))
             ) B
```

Returns

```
Narrative           Has_KX  Digits
simon says KX1234   1       1234
Tracy Jones kx 2456 1       2456
KX3887Candy min     1       3887
Shelly 9876         0       9876
3424Tom             0       3424
kx5436michaelstone  1       5436
4353 Diana          0       4353
kx Anglia           1       NULL
9387                0       9387
kx 2423             1       2423
kx4645              1       4645
James tin           0       NULL
receipted twice     0       NULL
12322452 AG         0       12322452
```

> **EDIT - I should add**

If your source contains multiple strings of digits (i.e. kx12345 Amy 789) it will return 12345789

Answer (score 0):

Another approach which is easily customizable and will get you the same results with a super efficient execution plan:

```
Declare @YourTable table (Narrative varchar(50))
Insert Into @YourTable values
('simon says KX1234'), ('Tracy Jones kx 2456'), ('KX3887Candy min'), ('Shelly 9876'),
('3424Tom'), ('kx5436michaelstone'), ('4353 Diana'), ('kx Anglia'), ('9387'), ('kx 2423'),
('kx4645'), ('James tin'), ('receipted twice '), ('12322452 AG');


WITH pos AS 
(
  SELECT 
    Narrative,
    Case1 = PATINDEX('%kx [0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]%',Narrative),
    Case2 = PATINDEX('%kx[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]%',Narrative),
    Case3 = PATINDEX('%[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]%',Narrative),
    Case4 = PATINDEX('%[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]%',Narrative)
  FROM @YourTable
)
SELECT 
  Narrative,
  HasKX  = SIGN(CHARINDEX('kx', Narrative)),
  Digits = 
  CASE 
    WHEN case1 > 0 THEN SUBSTRING(Narrative, Case1+3, 4)
    WHEN case2 > 0 THEN SUBSTRING(Narrative, Case2+2, 4)
    WHEN case3 > 0 THEN SUBSTRING(Narrative, Case3, 8)
    WHEN case4 > 0 THEN SUBSTRING(Narrative, Case4, 4)
  END
FROM pos;
```